# Status is zero in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, rest, xmlhttprequest

I have to call Rest Services using Javascript. My code is:

```
function CreateXMLHttpRequest() {
  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (typeof ActiveXObject != "undefined") {
    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  } else {
    throw new Error("XMLHttpRequestnot supported");
  }
}
function CallWebService() {
  objXMLHttpRequest = CreateXMLHttpRequest();
  objXMLHttpRequest.open("POST", "http://www.rest.net/services/abc.svc/json/GetXml", true);
  objXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml;charset=UTF-8");
  var packet = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><CompanyRequest xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/abc.DomainModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><CompanyName>company</CompanyName></CompanyRequest>';
  objXMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (objXMLHttpRequest.readyState == 4&&objXMLHttpRequest.status==200) {
      alert(objXMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    }
  }
  objXMLHttpRequest.send(packet);
}
```

The status is 200 in IE and I am able to get a response. But in Firefox and Chrome, the status is 0. How can I overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting a document at http://www.rest.net and I assume you are on a different domain. In this case you are victim of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and your calls are blocked.

It might work in IE if you have set http://www.rest.net as a trusted domain.

Comment: There are techniques that allow cross-domain communication, like CORS or JSONP, and you'll need to check if your Web service allows them. If not, you cannot call the Web service with JavaScript and you'll need to find another way.

Comment: Can u tell me how can i use these techniques?

Comment: The Web service you are calling should document this. If not, most likely it means that they are not supported. For JSONP, jQuery is a good place to start: http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/